# Can cache data be destroyed between apc_exist() and apc_fetch() calls within the same script?

Tags: php, caching, apc

In the following example

```
if (apc_exists('foo'))
{
    echo apc_fetch('foo');
}
```

Is it possible that `apc_exists('foo')` returns `TRUE` but `apc_fetch('foo')` returns `FALSE` because the data was deleted (manually or due to cache reset) between those two calls?

Answer (score 1):

From what I read in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) it's designed to be consistent per request:

> After the ttl has passed, the stored variable will be expunged from the cache (**on the 
>     next request**)

OTH If you have something like `apc_delete()` on another thread a Non-Repeatable Read is possible. I would recommend to refactor your code to one atomic `apc_fetch()` only:

```
$foo = apc_fetch("foo", $exist);
if ($exist) {
    echo $foo;

}
```

Comment: '_on the next request_' - does that mean `apc_fetch()` or the next HTTP request? I'm sure it's the former. Also, to play devil's advocate with myself, if I need to refactor my code as you've suggested, why should the `apc_exist()` method event exist?

Comment: I understand request as HTTP request. If you read the complete documentation the context becomes more clear. `apc_exists()` exists probably for use cases where you just need to know of the existence. Don't ask me for such a use case. Plus there was a period where apc_fetch() had no second parameter. BTW you don't have to refactor your code if you know that no other thread will remove the variable (no `apc_delete()` or `apc_clear()`).